# chosen-rails error chosen is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen-rails for integration of chosen.js with rails asset pipeline

I have included in my Gemfile

```
gem 'chosen-rails'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

in my application.js I have

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require_self
```

in my application.css I have

```
 *= require chosen
```

The page loads the js as required

```
/assets/jquery.js?body=1
/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1
/assets/lib/select-parser.js?body=1
/assets/chosen.jquery.js?body=1
```

But I I try to use the function chosen() it gives the error chosen is not a function

```
$('#whatever').chosen();
```

I have tried the above in the footer. inside Jquery ready.. inside firebug console.. nothing seems to work. What can possibly be the issue ???

Comment: I have a sample app that shows the problem at https://github.com/mabid/chosen-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem was not with jQuery or asset pipeline or the chosen-rails gem instead it was a server configuration issue and wrong files were being served due to bad nginx configuration.

Comment: Having the same problem. do you remember what was wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Please elaborate on the configuration issue

Comment: I also had nginx configured, and the assets requests were going through that instead of the rails app server causing the issue, very rare chance you have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that jQuery was included both in `application.js` (v1.11.1) and also in my layout via CDN (v2.1.4).

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I kept the CDN version at the beginning of my header, removed `//= require jquery` from `application.js` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it brought me here. For me I was including both jquery and chosen twice in my application. Doubly including either may cause this error.