# Trouble with chosen and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to implement visual tags, as based on the Railscasts episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

For some reason the chosen library cannot be found (see error below from the javascript console). I'm also a bit concerned there are all those bootstrap errors.

application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require chosen
*= require_tree .
```

sentences.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    $('#sentence_tag_list').chosen()
```

from edit/form view

```
<div class="sentence">
  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list, label: false, :input_html => {multiple: true}  %>
</div>
```

Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.3.0.0"
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'font_awesome_rails'
  gem 'chosen-rails'  # for tag formatting
end
```

Error messages from javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap-transition.js:30
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-affix.js:72
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-alert.js:72
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-button.js:68
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-carousel.js:159
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-collapse.js:127
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-dropdown.js:138
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-modal.js:199
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-scrollspy.js:125
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-tab.js:114
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-tooltip.js:327
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-popover.js:38
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-typeahead.js:295
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'chosen' sentences.js?body=1:3
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

**EDIT**

Additional info: I just noticed in the rendered page source two links to the chosen libray.

```
<script src="/assets/chosen.jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/chosen-jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I click on the first I see a javascript library. The second link just returns a blank page.

**EDIT 2**

I managed to remove the bootstrap errors by moving *require bootstrap* after jquery, but a still getting the chosen error.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

** EDIT 3**

Related question: [chosen-rails error chosen is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874093/chosen-rails-error-chosen-is-not-a-function?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

After much searching and modifying of code, I changed the static assets directive in *config/environments/development.rb*

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: PS If anyone can explain what happened here I will accept it as an answer.